# Como evitar uma IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification?

Tags: java, android, listview, multithreading, android-adapter

Tenho uma `Activity` que exibe uma `ListView`, à qual está associado um `Adapter` "backed by" uma `ArrayList` global. Se eu acrescentar um elemento a essa `ArrayList`, o ideal é que o faça no thread principal e imediatamente chame `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` a fim de evitar uma *"IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification"*. Porém essa `ArrayList` é alterada por um thread secundário, executado por um `Service` que nem sempre está acoplado à `Activity` e portanto nem sempre tem uma referência ao `Adapter` para que possa solicitar ao thread principal a execução dessas duas operações. E aí quando (imagino eu) o thread principal se depara com a lista alterada, a exceção acaba acontecendo.

Vejo duas alternativas para resolver isso:

1. Tornar o `Adapter` global para poder chamá-lo no momento que eu quiser.
2. Criar uma *deep copy* da lista e associar a cópia ao `Adapter`. De forma que quando a lista original for alterada a cópia permanece intocada até o momento que o thread principal precisar exibir a alteração (no `Activity.onResume()`, por exemplo). Daí eu altero a cópia a partir da original e chamo `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

A desvantagem da primeira na minha opinião é tornar o código confuso com a presença de um objeto fora do seu escopo correto, pois o certo a rigor seria mantê-lo apenas pelo período de vida da `Activity` que o utiliza. As desvantagens da segunda são a redundância que aparenta ser desnecessária e a ocupação extra de memória (apesar que a lista não é muito grande, no máximo uns 500 objetos de uns 12 campos cada). Há outras vantagens e desvantagens nessas duas opções? Existe uma terceira opção?

Postei também no [SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21113055/how-to-avoid-in-this-case-the-illegalstateexception-the-content-of-the-adapter).

Comment: Estamos discutindo como usar tags neste caso: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/468/existem-tags-implicitas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resposta correta é não alterar o Adapter em uma Background thread, a própria exceção já alerta para isso...

```java
        ......
        } else if (mItemCount != mAdapter.getCount()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The content of the adapter has changed but "
                    + "ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of "
                    + "your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from "
                    + "the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() "
                    + "when its content changes. [in ListView(" + getId() + ", " + getClass()
                    + ") with Adapter(" + mAdapter.getClass() + ")]");
        }
        ....
```

**EDIT**

Uma forma de resolver o problema seria utilizar um [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) para salvar os dados recebidos em seu serviço.

Já na sua Activity você deveria utilizar um [CursorAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) para sua List/GridView.

Para garantir a consistência dos dados da lista (e manter as queries fora da UI Thread), a leitura dos dados deve ser feita com um [CursorLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html), pois esse registra automaticamente um ContentObserver para manter seu Cursor sempre atualizado.

Mais informações sobre CursorLoader no treinamento [Loading Data in Background](https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/index.html) e sobre [Content Providers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).

Para a criação do Content Provider eu normalmente utilizo o [ContentProviderCodeGenerator](https://github.com/foxykeep/ContentProviderCodeGenerator)

Comment: Para o caso geral está correto, na verdade essa resposta já consta na própria pergunta... a pergunta porém se refere a um caso específico.

Comment: Não sei como são seus dados, ou como é feito a atualizacão da lista. Se você baixa apenas os itens novos, poderia postar os novos itens para a Activity usando um Message Bus, e la adicionar ao Adapter e chamar o notifyDatasetChanged(), ou então utilizar um DB com CursorAdapter (e CursorLoader)

Comment: Itens novos chegam individualmente, por isso o problema consiste em acrescentar um item à lista. Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de cada opção?

Comment: Utilizando um ContentProvider, você pode continuar populando seus dados em um Service em background. Já o CursorLoader já se encarrega de manter o CursorAdapter atualizado (ele registra um ContentObserver e faz a atualizacão do Cursor automaticamente)

Comment: Estou propenso a aceitar essa resposta, apesar dela não mencionar vantagens/desvantagens das primeiras duas opções citadas na pergunta. A opção de CursorLoader também foi mencionada na questão postada no SO em inglês e parece ser a mais acertada, por tirar proveito dos recursos da API.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um `BroadcastReceiver` na sua atividade e fazer o service enviar a nova `ArrayList` como um extra do `Intent` para ele. Daí o receiver faz o processamento da nova lista e chama o `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Note que nesta solução você precisa também fazer com sua atividade se conecte ao `Service` no `onCreate()` para fazer a requisição da lista atualizada quando ela for iniciada.

Comment: Acho que faltou avisar: o serviço e as atividades podem estar funcionando em momentos diferentes. Não posso garantir uma atividade em primeiro plano o tempo todo que o serviço roda para relegar a ela a adição do item à lista. E prefiro não manter a mesma lista em locais distintos, necessito dela sempre atualizada para quando uma atividade precisar e o serviço não estiver rodando.

Comment: Por isso que quando você iniciar a atividade você deve se conectar ao Servico para requisitar a versão mais atual da lista.

Comment: Não vejo problema em manter duas versões da lista se ela for atualizada em apenas um lugar. Ou seja, sua implementação deve garantir que o serviço é responsável pela lista mais atual (tipo um provider). A atividade então simplesmente faz ou recebe requisições do serviço quando precisar.

Comment: Nesse caso o `BroadcastReceiver` acrescenta uma complexidade ao código que poderia funcionar de maneira mais simples com a alternativa 2 da questão. Além disso, um serviço que roda o tempo todo sem entregar valor contínuo é considerado um anti-pattern.

Comment: O uso do `BroadcastReceiver` é bastante simples e não custa quase nada de memória. Você não postou nenhum código mas sua segunda opção me parece mais complexa.

Comment: A parte mais complicada da solução 2 na minha opinião é o _deep copy_. Na verdade  a solução do `BroadcastReceiver` iria necessitar um _deep copy_ para enviar uma cópia da lista para a atividade ao invés de uma referência, caso contrário ocorreria uma `IllegalStateException` da mesma forma.

Comment: Uma correção: provavelmente estou enganado sobre a necessidade de fazer _deep copy_ na solução do `BroadcastReceiver`, pois os extras do intent são serializados e portanto já ocorre uma _deep copy_.